# HTTP compression in IIS 7.5 on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iis-7.5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a load balanced, auto scaling Elastic Beanstalk IIS 7.5 application. I would like to enable HTTP compression on the deployed application (same way as it is described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)). Is it at all possible to do? Even if I would try to set it up manually on one instance via Remote Desktop (in my current setup EC2 instances are in a private subnet), what will happen when the application will scale up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just enabled `<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true"/>` under `<system.webServer>` section in my `web.config` and the compression started working as expected.